# counting unique row values in excel

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, excel-2013, unique-values

I have product list like this. I have only product name list

```
Apple       1
Apple       1
Apple       1
Orange      2
Orange      2
Orange      2
Mango       3
Mango       3
Pineapple   4
Pineapple   4
Pineapple   4
Pineapple   4
Pineapple   4
Pineapple   4
Avocado     5
```

I want to count data in this way. please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numbering unique values in a worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366816/numbering-unique-values-in-a-worksheet)

Answer (score 1):

Put **1** in B1 then put this formula in B2,

```
=if(a2<>a1, max(b$1:b1)+1, b1)
```

... and fill down.

Alternately just put his formula into B1,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A$1:A1)))
```

... and fill down.

Answer (score 1):

In B1 insert 1 and in B2 insert:

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1,B1+1)
```

And from there just fill.

Comment: You are welcome :) FYI accepting an answer will increase your reputation.